# Conditional Formatting of asp:Label based on database value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have labels in a ListView that display the size and finish of an object (an SKU). I would like to change the color of the font of those labels if that particular SKU is "in stock" (has a stockedid of 1). The stocked attribute is part of the table with the size and finish, but it is not displayed. I have looked for a solution, but nothing seems to be exactly what I want, since I am not displaying the information that is used to format the label.

Please "speak slowly" :-) as I'm a relative novice with this type of thing. (As is probably evident.)

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewSSD" runat="server" DataSourceID="SSD" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="sdoptions">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("SKU", "ST.aspx?SKU={0}") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image1path", "Images/{0}") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("length", "{0}\" x ") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("width", "{0}\"") %>'></asp:Label>                     
        <asp:Label ID="finishLabel" runat="server" cssClass="tinyprint" Text='<%# Eval("finish", "({0})") %>' />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "spot" or party room for formatting is in general the row data bind event.

This event lets you get your hands on each row, and do formatting.

so, for a repeater, listview, gridview etc.?

row data bind.

And note that "during" the data bind process, the full database row that you feed the data aware object (listview, gridview etc.) is avaible.

So, say I full out a listview with list of hotels, but for "active" hotels, I want say to highlight in blue. While the column "active" is in the data source, it not on the listview.

So then say this:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="MyHotels" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID"
              OnItemDataBound="MyHotels_ItemDataBound"   >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>' /> </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                    <td runat="server"><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:350px">
                        <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" class="btn"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                 <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
                     class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <tr runat="server" style="">
                                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                                    <th runat="server">Description</th>
                                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">View Hotel</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

My code to fill:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        MyHotels.DataSource = rstData;
        MyHotels.DataBind();
    }
```

And we get/see this:

[image]

We set the font bold (for any active hotel).

We set font italic, and also background of the cell to blue.

That code was this:

```
    protected void MyHotels_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {

            DataRowView gData = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

            if ((bool)gData["Active"])
            {
                Label lblHotel = e.Item.FindControl("HotelNameLabel") as Label;
                lblHotel.Font.Bold = true;
                lblHotel.Font.Italic = true;

                // get holdring cell
                HtmlTableCell mycell = lblHotel.Parent as HtmlTableCell;
                mycell.BgColor = "skyblue";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Although your solution didn't quite work for my novice level of understanding, your answer DID point me to a solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Albert Kallal's answer, I was able to find another article that helped me to find an easy-for-me solution.

```
protected void ListViewSSD_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label Label8;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Label8 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label8");

            System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            string stockstatus = rowView["stockedid"].ToString();
            if (stockstatus == "1")
            {
                Label8.Font.Bold = true;
                Label8.CssClass = "greenitalic";
            }
        }
        Label Label9;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Label9 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label9");

            System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            string stockstatus = rowView["stockedid"].ToString();
            if (stockstatus == "1")
            {
                Label9.Font.Bold = true;
                Label9.CssClass = "greenitalic";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the article I was referencing for a solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound?view=netframework-4.8